# CoffeeScript on Rails - selecionar itens de uma tabela

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails4, coffeescript

Olá! tenho o seguinte código gerado pelo Scaffold:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Produtos</h1>

<table class="table table-striped" id="tabelaProdutos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preco</th>
      <th>Descricao</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @produtos.each do |produto| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= produto.nome %></td>
        <td><%= produto.preco %></td>
        <td><%= produto.descricao %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', produto %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_produto_path(produto) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', produto, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="botaosomar" value="OK" onclick="select()" />

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Produto', new_produto_path %>
```

Preciso fazer com que os itens dessa tabela sejam selecionados e que através de um botão, eu possa somar os valores Float(coluna "Preco") desses itens selecionados. A questão é que sou péssimo em javascript e desconheço CoffeeScript. Não sei por onde começar e não encontrei um tutorial didático sobre CoffeeScript.
Esta necessidade faz parte de um trabalho da faculdade.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, então vamos criar a possibilidade de seleção dos itens da tabela alterando a linha do código HTML da seguinte forma:

`<td><input type="checkbox"value=<%= produto.preco %>><%= produto.preco %></td>`

E depois de `</table>`:

```html
<div id="total">

</div>
```

E no seu produto.coffee vai o código:

```js
$(document).ready ->
  somaSelecionados = ->
    n = $('input:checked').length
    sum = 0
    $('input:checked').each ->
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val())
      return
    $('#total').text n + (if n == 1 then ' is' else ' are') + ' checked:' + sum
    return

  somaSelecionados()
  
  $('#soma').on 'click', somaSelecionados
```

Comment: A soma não é feita com todos os elementos da tabela. Apenas com o que eu selecionar com o mouse.

Comment: Veja se consegue testar a nova solução , acho que vai funcionar tudo agora.